# number of ways to partition an integer.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

A partition of a positive integer n is a way of writingn as a sum of positive integers.

Two sums
that differ only in the order of their summands are considered the same partition.

For example,
4 can be partitioned in five distinct ways:

4

3 + 1

2 + 2

2 + 1 + 1

1 + 1 + 1 + 1

Let q(n) be the number of partitions of n into powers of 2 (Here q(0) = 1, q(1) = 1).

For
instance, if n = 4, we have

4

2 + 2

2 + 1+ 1

1 + 1 + 1 + 1

Show that q(n) is even for all n ≥ 2. Give a combinatorial proof.

Answer (score 4):

Use induction. Check the base cases.

Let's look at the partitions of $2n+1$. Every partition of $2n+1$ includes odd number of $1$s. If a partition contains $2k+1$ $1$s, all the other terms in it are even. This kind of partitions can be identified with partitions of $n-k$ by dividing the even numbers by $2$. So, $q(2n+1)=q(n)+q(n-1)+\ldots+q(2)+q(1)+1$, where $1$ at the end stands for the partition consists solely of $1$s. As everything except $q(1)$ is even in this sum, $q(2n+1)$ is also  even.

Now, look at the partitions of $2n$. A partition contains an even number of $1$s. If a partition contains $2k$ $1$s, all the other terms in it are even. This kind of partitions can be identified with partitions of $n-k$ by dividing the even numbers by $2$. So, $q(2n)=q(n)+q(n-1)+\ldots+q(2)+q(1)+1$, where $1$ at the end stands for the partition consists solely of $1$s. As everything except $q(1)$ is even in this sum, $q(2n)$ is also  even.

Comment: What do you mean by " This kind of partitions can be identified with partitions of n-k by dividing the even numbers by 1. " ???

Comment: In your answer q(2n+1) = q(n) + ... + q(1) + 1 = q(2n). ????? what happend ?

Comment: @user331899 There is a one-to-one correspondence between the partitions of $n-k$ (into powers of two) and the partitions of $2n+1$ which use exactly $2k+1$ copies of $1$.

Comment: There was a typo, 1 should be 2. In how many partitions of 5, we use exactly 2 1s? 0 because other than 1 every other power of two is even but, if we use even number of 1s the sum would be even, whereas 5 is odd. In how many partitions of 5, we use exactly one 1? This question is the same thing as the following: in how many ways can we partition 4 into powers of 2 that are at least two? Every such partition in fact is a regular partition of 4/2=2 multiplied by 2. Like 122--11, 14-2

Comment: How can you explain q(2n+1) = q(n) + q(n-1) + ... + q(1) + 1

Comment: and q(2n) = q(n) + q(n-1) + ... + q(1) + 1 and hence q(2n) = q(2n+1) ?

Comment: Divide the partitions of $2n+1$ into groups according to the number of $1$s used in the partition. The number of partitions with $2k+1$ $1$s is equal to $q(n-k)$. Then, sum these all up to get $q(2n+1)=q(n)+q(n-1)+\ldots+q(1)+1$.

Comment: Yes $q(2n+1)=q(2n)$. Consider the following bijection: for every partition of $2n$ add a $1$ to get a new partition of $2n+1$. Each distinct partition of $2n$ gives a unique partition of $2n+1$ by this process. So, this map from the partitions of $2n$ to the partitions of $2n+1$ is injective and well-defined. Moreover, every partition of $2n+1$ contains at least one $1$. So, every partition of $2n+1$ can be obtained by adding $1$ to a partition of $2n$. Thus, the map from the partitions of $2n$ to the partitions of  $2n+1$ is surjective. So, it is a bijection,i.e. two sets have the same cardin